# How do you pronounce abstract?

Tags: pronunciation

> In the past it was always enough to be connected to humanity in a more
>   abstract way, by the glint of possibility. ([Kathy Holwadel](http://thisibelieve.org/essay/15305/)) [[her pronunciation]](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/397)

**abstract /æbˈstrækt/**

Although there is the difference between first /æ/ and second /æ/ by accentuation, the first seems quite different from the second one. So I hear even /ɛ/ or /ə/ instead of /æ/. I want to know if she really pronounces /æ/. If yes, what is the difference from the second one?

Comment: Note that *abstract* is pronounced differently depending on whether it is a noun or an adjective. As an adjective the second syllable is stressed; when it appears as a noun the first syllable is stressed.

Comment: This is partially a matter of the difference in phonetic context: the vowel before a continuant or voiced stop is different than the "same" vowel before a voiceless stop. (The difference is generally more strongly marked in US English than in British; often, as here, the vowel before a voiced stop or continuant is tenser and diphthongalized.) The other part is idiolectal variation: note Ms. Holwadel's pronunciation of *past*, in which the /æ/ is likewise close to /ɛ/.

Comment: @WendiKidd- Interestingly, I pronounce abstract as a noun and as an adjective the same way- with the first syllable stressed.  *Here's the abstract for my paper*.   And *I like this abstract painting*.   It's when abstract is used as a verb, that I stress the second syllable.  *We need to abstract the transport mechanism from the interface*.

Comment: I don't know that anyone is going to answer this question as good as StoneyB did, so I've converted that to an answer. @StoneyB: If you want it as an answer, simply answer it, and alert me, then I'll delete this comment and the community wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*From StoneyB's comment:*

This is partially a matter of the difference in phonetic context: the vowel before a continuant or voiced stop is different than the "same" vowel before a voiceless stop. (The difference is generally more strongly marked in US English than in British; often, as here, the vowel before a voiced stop or continuant is tenser and diphthongalized.) The other part is idiolectal variation: note Ms. Holwadel's pronunciation of past, in which the /æ/ is likewise close to /ɛ/.